# Failed to receive push notification when application is running on the background or unused in a long time

Tags: ios, push-notification, wamp-protocol

I am really new to iOS programming and I have got a pretty tough question regarding Push Notification.

I have to use Wamp as the push server instead of the APNS. And there comes the problem. I would really like to know if it is solvable or using APNS is the only way to get things done.
(* I am using MDWamp to connect the server.)

The program fails to receive the push message under two circumstances which are listed as following:

Case 1. The program is running on the background;

Case 2. The program is running on the foreground but stays idle for quite a long time.

However, the local push notification pops out as soon as I bring the program back on the foreground(for Case 1) or click somewhere(for Case 2).

I would be very much appreciated if someone could help me out.